# how to split a URL for get the id php

Tags: php, url, split

i have this URL:

```
www.blublub.de/niedersachsen.html?veranstaltung=Neumarkt+Osnabrück~W011Cb5ETzN2EJoG9N~10.04.2014
```

And i like to get the `id-number **"W011Cb5ETzN2EJoG9N"**` from the URL.

How can i implement this in php ?

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$parts=explode('~', $_GET['veranstaltung']);

$id=$parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <?php        
    $veranstaltung=$_GET['veranstaltung'];        
    $str=explode('~',$veranstaltung);
    $idnumber=$str[1];
    echo $idnumber;
    ?>
```

get and `explode` it

Answer (score 0):

try to get and explode with (~) your url query string

```
$url = $_GET['veranstaltung'];
 $myid = explode('~', $url);
 echo $myid[1]; // output - W011Cb5ETzN2EJoG9N
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular exp for this

```
if (preg_match_all("/~(.*?)~/",$_GET['veranstaltung'],$result){
   print_R($result)
}
```